# htaccess multiple possible parameters rewrite urls

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Im trying to get nice URLS for my website, but it's not working yet.

On my site a got various pages:
?p=page:

This defines my current page but I also have 1 page that contains up to 2 more parameters:
?p=page&g=variable2&m=variable3

The way I would want my URLs to look like is:
/page/variable2/variable3

Is there anyway to get this done?

Currently I have tried this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?p=$1&g=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?p=$1&g=$2&m=3 [L]
```

Inside my code I refer everything to ?p=page&g=variable2&m=variable3. Do I need to change this within my code to the new nice url?

Comment: make index.php non-rewritable, for instance `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]`

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: @starkeen when I go to the homepage of my website it is still displaying: ?p=home instead of /home.

Comment: Does it work  when you go to `example.com/home` instead of `example.com/index.php?p=home` ?

Comment: @starkeen if i go to /home I automatically get: /home?p=home also if I go to /about I get /about?p=home instead of /about?p=about

Comment: Do you have any other  rules?

Comment: @starkeen No I just started with mod-rewrite for the first time.